# Rand Paul coronavirus vote record

Tags: united-states, economy, republican-party, covid-19, libertarianism

I've seen mentioned in an article [from March](https://www.newsweek.com/rand-pauls-father-wrote-coronavirus-hoax-article-days-before-son-tested-positive-covid-19-1493662) that:

> Earlier this month, [Rand] Paul, a licensed physician, voted against a bipartisan $8 billion emergency coronavirus funding bill. He was the sole senator to vote against.

How did he vote on the subsequent, even bigger, Covid-related stimulus  packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see [here](https://votesmart.org/bill/votes/71408#.XpFe8yUo-Ec) how Paul voted on the bill you mention in your question, when he was the sole Senator to vote against the Coronavirus Preparedness and Response Supplemental Appropriations Act. Subsequently, he also was one of [eight Republicans](https://votesmart.org/bill/votes/71516#.XpFfjyUo-Ec) who voted against the Families First Coronavirus Response Act.

As Paul tested positive for COVID-19 on or before 22nd March, and went into quarantine, he was unable to take part in the various cloture votes on the CARES Act, nor the subsequent [96-0 vote](https://votesmart.org/bill/votes/71699#.XpFgXSUo-Ec) on the final bill, and is recorded as not voting.

Interestingly, he did [release a statement](https://votesmart.org/public-statement/1410560/dr-rand-paul-announces-his-covid-19-recovery-act#.XpFglCUo-Ec) on March 20th that said he would shortly introduce his COVID-19 Recovery Act, which he said would provide "relief to American families and businesses without adding to the skyrocketing debt that also threatens our country."

Given the passage of the CARES Act, this seems to have now been shelved.